# mouse failure on laptop Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, mouse

I have a laptop running Windows Vista, and when I am logged on the curser will not move.  However, when I log on as a different user, it DOES work.  What is up with that?

I did shut it down and tried rebooting it, but I do not know of any other problem solving techniques as I can not get to anything to click on it when I am logged on as myself.

Answer (score 1):

Have you plugged in an external mouse? If so, does it work?

If not, and you don't have an external mouse, can you navigate with the keyboard? If so, press `Windows` + `Break`, go into the `Device Manager`, and delete any installed pointing devices. Then reboot the computer from the Start menu.

Also, it may be something simple like the fact that you've disabled the touchpad, and you just need to look for a setting to re-enable it.

Give those options a chance and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely that in your user profile you have disabled the trackpad. This is easily done in most laptops. There is usually a FN + F key combination that will enable / disable the trackpad.
First things is to look for that, it will be a different colour (often blue) icon on one of your F keys e.g. F4 or F5 try pressing Fn and this key.

Certain makes have their own software to make this 'easy' for users to do. Check your make and model and Google 'enable trackpad' with your ake and model suffixed to the end. This should lead you in the right direction.

Otherwise please update the question with the make and model of the laptop.